# Can liquid soldering flux be refrigerated?

Tags: soldering, flux

I've been upgrading my soldering mojo lately and have collected an assortment of liquid fluxes.

The [Kester 951](http://www.kester.com/download/951%20Soldering%20Flux%20Data%20Sheet.pdf) and [Kester 186](http://www.kester.com/download/186%20Soldering%20Flux%20Data%20Sheet.pdf) datasheets state shelf lives (1 and 2 years respectively) when stored between 10-25°C (50-77°F).

I store my *solder* paste in the fridge, which is between 2-5°C (35-40°F).

Is the liquid soldering flux safe in there too? And would keeping it there extend its shelf life?

Also I guess I don't know how I could tell it had gone past its prime. What would be the signs it had "expired", whether or not the shelf life period had elapsed?

Comment: This is just to pile-up references.  [Here's a recent article](http://pcdandf.com/pcdesign/index.php/current-issue/239-tech-tips/10347-tech-tips-1510) about handling of solder paste in the industrial shops.

Answer (score 1):

I have a liquid rosin solder flux that I keep in my garage (40F-100F non-controlled temp).  It is over 25 years old & it works perfectly even after that much time.  I suggest you avoid any solder flux that requires refrigeration.

To answer your question--I doubt it will cause a problem for your flux. To be on the safe side though, I would suggest you consult the manufacture's website or contact them via email/phone--which ever is easiest for you.

hth

Best regards